# Ошибка в dbUnit

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc, junit

При запуске теста в dbUnit выскакивает ошибка 
org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: CLIENTS

сам код

```
public class TestDataService extends DBTestCase {

@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("C:\\Users\\Игарек\\IdeaProjects\\proff1_examples_boot\\src\\test\\resorces\\TestDataSet.xml"));

}
public TestDataService(String testName) throws Exception {
    super(testName);

    System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS,
            "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL,
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_boot?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
    System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME,
            "root");
    System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD,
            "root");
    System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA,
            "data");
}
public void test() throws Exception {

    DataService dataService = new DataService();
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setIdObject((long) 1);
    data.setDateModified("2018-09-19T13:12:21.136263+03:00");
    data.setDatePublished("2018-09-19T13:12:21.136232+03:00");
    data.setDocumentOf("tender");
    data.setDocumentType("subContract");
    data.setFormat("text/plain");
    data.setHash("md5:232dba893a22ac722249ad92f8bccf22");
    data.setId("4f6d6dc59d1844bb80143ccc2e727a2f");
    data.setTitle("11.09.2018.xlsx");
    data.setUrl("https://public-docs-sandbox.prozorro.gov.ua/get/3500487074064bd98f1076c21fe69e9a?KeyID=1331dc52&Signature=w%252BTQLJCiU%2FDQXfp%2FxB0VfDNRzImPv7zch3e8H1jfVOZrDJZuam%2FOTVLlvpdUiz9WVLHdUzdMrQJclbl4Vs28CQ%253D%253D");
    dataService.save(data);
    IDataSet databaseDataSet = getConnection().createDataSet();
    ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable("data");

    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataSalaryTestDataSet_Expected.xml"));

    ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("data");
    ITable filteredActualTable = DefaultColumnFilter.includedColumnsTable(actualTable, expectedTable.getTableMetaData().getColumns());

    Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, filteredActualTable);


} }
```

В чем проблема? У меня нету таблицы CLIENTS т.д.

Comment: В какой строке вылетает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

уже разобрался, выскакивает эта ошибка когда несколько схем имеют таблицы с тем же именем